# Windows: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, windows-10

I'm using Python 3.7.5 and Windows 10. I installed `matplotlib` via `pip` but now if I run:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\Pol\Documents\Python\hallo.py", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Just to be sure: You do not have different python versions installed in parallel?

Comment: I first installed Python 3.8 then uninstalled it and installed Python 3.7.5 so I guess I only have one version by now. At least when I input `python --version` I only get `Python 3.7.5`

Comment: A while ago I had similar issues, and I have different python versions installed, that's why I am asking. `python --version` just shows the first version, not all that are installed. In my case, if I type `pip` at the command line, and hit than several times the `tab`-key, I get shown the pip-versions for all python versions I have installed, e.g. `pip2.7` and `pip3.7`.

Comment: `where python` would output a list of all pythons you have. Most probably you installed matplotlib in the wrong one of those.